# How can i provide a a value for an argument in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I'm very new to GraphQL, and i'm trying to perform some example queries to [this graph](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2). In particular i'm trying the `User` schema.

According to that documentation, the schema is the following:

```
id: ID!
liquidityPositions: [LiquidityPosition!]
usdSwapped: BigDecimal!
```

And here is query i tried:

```
{
  user (where: {id: "0x7c9C48b7cBEbBDA3268435F20c81f15A538C566C"}) {
    id
    liquidityPositions
    usdSwapped
  }
}
```

This query fails, i keep getting the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 0,
          "column": 0
        }
      ],
      "message": "No value provided for required argument: `id`"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i provide the `id` field and where am i supposed to provide it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems with that query. First, to get a user by id, remove the "where" and curly braces from your query. Secondly, the liquityPositions field needs a selection of subfields. Like so:

```
{
  user (id: "0x7c9C48b7cBEbBDA3268435F20c81f15A538C566C") {
    id
    liquidityPositions {
      id
    }
    usdSwapped
  }
}
```

That website you linked to will show you errors with your query so you can interactively learn more about what is supported.

I would also suggest running through the introduction to GraphQL here: https://graphql.org/learn/ to get a handle on how things are done.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm going through the link you mentioned